# getting whole file in response instead of actual response

Tags: javascript, python, cgi

Actually I was trying to get some response from my .py script but instead of response I m getting the whole file .
This is the ajax call in the javascript file

```
$.ajax({                                                                                                                                                                  
        url: "py/simple.py",                                                                                                                                                  
        type: "POST",                                                                                                                                                         
        data: {foo: 'bar', bar: 'foo'},                                                                                                                                       
        success: function(response){                                                                                                                                          
            log(response);                                                                                                                                                    
            $("#div").html(response);                                                                                                                                         
        }                                                                                                                                                                     
    });
```

And this is the py script

```
import cgi, cgitb
cgitb.enable()  # for troubleshooting                                                                                                                                             

#the cgi library gets vars from html                                                                                                                                              
data = cgi.FieldStorage()
#this is the actual output                                                                                                                                                        
print "Content-Type: text/plain\n"
print "The foo data is: " + data["foo"].value
print "<br />"
print "The bar data is: " + data["bar"].value
print "<br />"
print data
```

And the response I m getting is the whole

```
import cgi, cgitb 
cgitb.enable()  # for troubleshooting

#the cgi library gets vars from html
data = cgi.FieldStorage()
#this is the actual output
print "Content-Type: text/plain\n"
print "The foo data is: " + data["foo"].value
print "<br />"
print "The bar data is: " + data["bar"].value
print "<br />"
print data
```

Any help ??

Comment: I think you forgot to make your python file executable. You can do it using chmod +x command.

Comment: I have done that.still not working :(

Comment: If you don't have a really good reason to use CGI, I would *strongly* suggest to use a web-framework instead of bare-bones CGI. Something like [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org) for example. Raw CGI is very error-prone and hard to debug!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a mis-configured webserver.  You need to tell it that your request is to execute cgi-bin (and not to serve back the file contents). Something like:

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/path/to/cgi-bin/folder"
```

You can read more https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/cgi.html